# iTextSharp barcode placement

Tags: itext

I am printing Avery labels generated from using iTextSharp.  The last column of the three column sheet had to be moved over a little so I added some spaces:

```
                 case 3:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 12:
            case 15:
                //fmp first
                iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunkFmp1 = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(string.Format("    {0}\n", patient.FmpSsn));
                chunkFmp1.Font.SetFamily("Arial");
                chunkFmp1.Font.Size = fontsize;
                contents.Add(chunkFmp1);
                //name
                iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunkName1 = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(string.Format("    {0}\n", patient.PatientName));
                chunkName1.Font.SetFamily("Arial");
                chunkName1.Font.Size = fontsize;
                contents.Add(chunkName1);
                //data
                iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunkData1 = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(string.Format("    {0} {1} {2}\n", "SEX:" + patient.PatientSex.Substring(0, 1), "DOB:" + patient.PatientDobString, "AGE:" + patient.PatientAge));
                chunkData1.Font.SetFamily("Arial");
                chunkData1.Font.Size = fontsize;
                contents.Add(chunkData1);
                //data2
                iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunkBranch1 = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(string.Format("    {0} {1} {2} {3}\n", patient.BranchOfService, patient.BillingCode, patient.Rank, patient.ReligionName));
                chunkBranch1.Font.SetFamily("Arial");
                chunkBranch1.Font.Size = fontsize;
                contents.Add(chunkBranch1);
                break;
```

And that results in the following:

[image]

You can see how all of the text is moved over a little but not the barcode.  How do I align the barcode with the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I didn't realize there is a setting for placement of the barcode:

```
 contents.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(image39, 28, 0));
```

This pushes the code over 28 pixels (?) I think.